# How to send and receive protobuf data by rabbitmq with c

Tags: c, rabbitmq, protocol-buffers

I am new to rabbitmq and protobuf, is there some code example for sending and receiving protobuf data by rabbitmq with c language? thanks

Comment: The same way you send any other data by rabbitmq using C?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I have pasted the working code below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the Operation definition is below:

```
syntax = "proto2";

message Operation {
    required string operation = 1;
    optional int32 tracking_id = 2;
    optional double x = 3;
    optional double y = 4;
}
```

The send code:

```
Operation msg = OPERATION__INIT;
uint8_t *buf;
size_t len;
msg.operation = "d";
msg.tracking_id = 1;
msg.x = 0.5566;
msg.y = 0.2666;
msg.has_tracking_id = 1;
msg.has_x = 1;
msg.has_y = 1;
len = operation__get_packed_size(&msg);
buf = malloc(len);
operation__pack(&msg, buf);
amqp_bytes_t body;
body.len = len;
body.bytes = buf;
amqp_basic_publish(conn, 1, amqp_cstring_bytes(exchange),amqp_cstring_bytes(routingkey), 0, 0, &props, body);
free(buf);
```

The recive code:

```
amqp_rpc_reply_t res;
amqp_envelope_t envelope;

amqp_maybe_release_buffers(conn);

res = amqp_consume_message(conn, &envelope, NULL, 0);

if (AMQP_RESPONSE_NORMAL != res.reply_type)
{
   break;
}
fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", envelope.message.body.bytes);
fprintf(stderr, "%zu\n", envelope.message.body.len);
Operation *msg = operation__unpack(NULL, envelope.message.body.len, (const uint8_t *)envelope.message.body.bytes);
printf("operation:%s\n", msg->operation);
if (msg->has_tracking_id)
    printf("%d\n", msg->tracking_id);
if (msg->has_x)
    printf("%f\n", msg->x);
if (msg->has_y)
    printf("%f\n", msg->y);

amqp_destroy_envelope(&envelope);
```

Comment: I don't know what your question is, but in my opinion, freeing buf before using it is not a good idea.